# AngularJS and ASP.NET MVC data insert issue

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, crud, operation

I am inserting Data using AngularJS and ASP.NET MVC.
But I am facing issue that the data is inserted null.
What should I do?

**This is AngularJS file:**

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {
    debugger;
    $scope.InsertData = function () {
        var Action = document.getElementById("btnSave").getAttribute("value");
        if (Action == "Submit") {
            $scope.User = {};
            $scope.User.Username = $scope.Username;
            alert($scope.Username);
            $scope.User.Password = $scope.Password;
            $scope.User.Email = $scope.Email;
            $scope.User.Phone = $scope.Phone;
            $scope.User.DOB = $scope.DOB;

            $http({
                method: "post",
                url: "http://localhost:2776/Account/Insert_Employee",
                datatype: "json",
                data: JSON.stringify($scope.User)
            }).then(function (response) {
                alert("inserted");
            });
        }
    };
});
```

**This is HTML file:**

```
<div class="tab-content" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="register">
        <h3>Register Now !!!</h3>
        <p class="text-muted">Be cool and join today. Meet millions</p>

        <!--Register Form-->
        <form name="registration_form" id='registration_form' class="form-inline">
            <div class="row">

                <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
                    <label for="Username" class="sr-only">User Name</label>
                    <input id="Username" ng-model="Username" class="form-control input-group-lg" type="text" name="Username" title="Enter User name" placeholder="User name" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
                    <label for="email" class="sr-only">Email</label>
                    <input ng-model="Email" id="email" class="form-control input-group-lg" type="text" name="Email" title="Enter Email" placeholder="Your Email" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
                    <label for="Phone" class="sr-only">Phone</label>
                    <input ng-model="Phone" id="Phone" class="form-control input-group-lg" type="text" name="Phone" title="Enter Phone" placeholder="Your Phone" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
                    <label for="password" class="sr-only">Password</label>
                    <input ng-model="Password" id="password" class="form-control input-group-lg" type="password" name="password" title="Enter password" placeholder="Password" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <p class="birth"><strong>Date of Birth</strong></p>
                <div class="form-group col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
                    <label for="month" class="sr-only"></label>
                    <select class="form-control" id="day">
                        <option value="Day" disabled selected>Day</option>
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option>2</option>
                        <option>3</option>
                        <option>4</option>
                        <option>5</option>
                        <option>6</option>
                        <option>7</option>
                        <option>8</option>
                        <option>9</option>
                        <option>10</option>
                        <option>11</option>
                        <option>12</option>
                        <option>13</option>
                        <option>14</option>
                        <option>15</option>
                        <option>16</option>
                        <option>17</option>
                        <option>18</option>
                        <option>19</option>
                        <option>20</option>
                        <option>21</option>
                        <option>22</option>
                        <option>23</option>
                        <option>24</option>
                        <option>25</option>
                        <option>26</option>
                        <option>27</option>
                        <option>28</option>
                        <option>29</option>
                        <option>30</option>
                        <option>31</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
                    <label for="month" class="sr-only"></label>
                    <select class="form-control" id="month">
                        <option value="month" ng-model="DOB" disabled selected>Month</option>
                        <option>Jan</option>
                        <option>Feb</option>
                        <option>Mar</option>
                        <option>Apr</option>
                        <option>May</option>
                        <option>Jun</option>
                        <option>Jul</option>
                        <option>Aug</option>
                        <option>Sep</option>
                        <option>Oct</option>
                        <option>Nov</option>
                        <option>Dec</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <label for="year" class="sr-only"></label>
                    <select class="form-control" id="year">
                        <option value="year" disabled selected>Year</option>
                        <option>2000</option>
                        <option>2001</option>
                        <option>2002</option>
                        <option>2004</option>
                        <option>2005</option>
                        <option>2006</option>
                        <option>2007</option>
                        <option>2008</option>
                        <option>2009</option>
                        <option>2010</option>
                        <option>2011</option>
                        <option>2012</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group gender">
                <label class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" name="optradio" checked>Male
                </label>
                <label class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" name="optradio">Female
                </label>
            </div>

        </form><!--Register Now Form Ends-->
        <p><a href="#">Already have an account?</a></p>
        <button id="btnSave" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="InsertData()">Register Now</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**This is ASP.NET controller:**

```
public string Insert_Employee(User User)
{
    if (User != null)
    {
        using (Database1Entities Obj = new Database1Entities())
        {
            Obj.Users.Add(User);
            Obj.SaveChanges();
            return "Employee Added Successfully";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return "Employee Not Inserted! Try Again";
    }
}
```

I am entering data, but data is inserted as `null` into db. What should I do no?
I have added `<body ng-app="myApp">`
According to me there is no error
can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrote in this way your ajax call:
`$http({
                method: "post",
                url: "http://localhost:2776/Account/Insert_Employee",
                datatype: "json",
                data: {user:$scope.User}
            }).then(function (response) {
                alert("inserted");
            });`

Comment: make a parameter in lower case i.e. user